# Updating Opportunity Product field when Roll-Up Opportunity field is changed

Tags: workflow, opportunity-lineitem, roll-up-summary

Can anyone please help with a possible solution?

I have a Workflow on the Opportunity Products (Opportunity LineItems) that has one significant issue, which I can't workout how to solve.

The workflow seems to fire when desired and updates the Sales Price ('UnitPrice') field based on a calculation and certain criteria, BUT it is always one step behind i.e. it updates with the correct answer for the previous calculation, so if I then just 'Edit All' and re-save without amending anything it then has the correct answer (kind of catching up so to speak).  The formula uses a custom roll-up summary field, which is a subset value of the total Amount on the related Opportunity object.  What I think is happening is that the workflow is taking the Roll-up summary value before it is updated by the new total value of all the Opportunity LineItems and as a result it is applying the prior value.

Thank you in advance of your help,
Jonny

Comment: Please provide the criteria and I didnot find what field on what object the work flow is updating.

Comment: You're correct, the roll-up summary field is updated after the field updates, that were triggered by the workflow rules, made their changes. See [Triggers and Order of Execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm).

Comment: Wow - Thank you for quick responses.  Suri - if i strip it back the workflow just fires on Create or Edit of a Opportunity Product LineItem and the Action is a Field update to the Sales Price (UnitPrice) field on the opportunity Product lineItem.  The field update is a formula, which is a % multiplication of a custom Roll-up summary field on the Opportunity object of some of the Sales Prices across the Opportunity Product LineItems

Comment: Alex S - thank you for your confirmation too.  Have you any thoughts on what I could do to get around this issue without using Apex code (not something I'm in to, at least yet)?

Comment: Have you thought about multiplying the sales price of each opportunity Product lineItem by your % and then rolling up the values from the UnitPrice fields instead?

Comment: @AlexS - I'm not sure I'm fully understanding (sorry)  I've just tried an additional second Workflow, which uses the ISCHANGED(UnitPrice), but results hadn't improved.  I also alternatively tried it with an ISCHANGE() in a local formula field on the OppProd object which equals the Rollup summary field on the Opp object, but still no joy?  Incidentally, I've made sure the re-evaluate checkbox is ticked on both Workflows

Comment: @AlexS# I'm just considering if i could do your suggestion of multiplying the sales price % on the Opportunity Product and then summing the results.  I think it wouldn't work because of the nature of what I'm trying to do.  the percentage comes from a custom number field on the Product line item itself (% of maintenance) and then that % is applied to the total of all the Software lineitem to automatically calculate the dynamic Maintenance Sales Price

Comment: Apologies, the ISCHANGED(UnitPrice) suggestion wouldn't work because the field update can only apply to the same object. If you moved the Maintenance Sales Price to the Opportunity wouldn't the figure be the same (as long as the % is the same for all Products)? Alternatively this should be possible using the Process Builder, if the process was triggered when the roll-up field is changed. You can then update the child records. It's tricky to show the answer here though, did you want to message me on twitter (@aplssf) and set up a screen share?

Comment: So I've had a look and even the Process Builder won't work for you if you need to use a % from the Opportunity Product in order to adjust the Sales Price. Flows are the only other possibility but to be honest, it's probably easier to learn to write a Trigger for this! These [tutorials](http://www.sfdc99.com/beginner-tutorials/) are the best place to start if you're interested..

Comment: @AlexS I really have to leave work now, but will revisit tomorrow.  You've been really helpful so far.  If you are able to help again tomorrow or some time soon that would be great.  I'll feed back more tomorrow and perhaps get a twitter account working!

Comment: @Jonny did you have any thoughts on my answer (if you do, please comment on the answer, not the question)? Check out [this site](http://www.sfdc99.com/beginner-tutorials/) and you'll see that writing (and especially adapting code) isn't as bad as it looks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The roll-up summary field is only updated after the field updates, triggered by your workflow rules, have been completed. See [Triggers and Order of Execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm).

I'm not aware of a workaround which you could implement, without using code. So have a go at adapting the below.

*Note -
This is an After trigger because changing the Opportunity Product's `UnitPrice` will cause the Opportunity `Amount` field to recalculate, causing the recursive trigger error.*

*This will update the Sales Price of all Opportunity Products which are related to the Opportunity which has just had it's roll-up field update. I'm guessing that that's what you'll want but if not, let me know.*

**Trigger**

```
trigger UnitPriceUpdate on Opportunity (after update) {

    Map<Id,Decimal> softwareRevenue = new Map<Id,Decimal>();
    List<Opportunity> upOpps = new List<Opportunity>();
    List<OpportunityLineItem> upOppProds = new List<OpportunityLineItem>();
    Decimal oppExpRev;

    for(Opportunity o : Trigger.new){
        Opportunity oldOpp = Trigger.oldMap.get(o.Id);
        //change Software_Line_Item__c to roll-up field name
        if(oldOpp.Software_Line_Item__c != o.Software_Line_Item__c){
            //do the same here
            softwareRevenue.put(o.Id,o.Software_Line_Item__c);
            upOpps.add(o);
        }
    }
    //replace prcntge_of_maintenance__c with formula field containing % on Opportunity Product
    for(OpportunityLineItem oli : [SELECT Id, prcntge_of_maintenance__c, OpportunityId FROM OpportunityLineItem
                                    WHERE OpportunityId IN :upOpps])
    {
        oppExpRev = softwareRevenue.get(oli.OpportunityId);
        //replace prcntge_of_maintenance__c with formula field containing % that you want to apply on Opportunity Product
        oli.UnitPrice = oppExpRev*oli.prcntge_of_maintenance__c;
        upOppProds.add(oli);
    }
    update upOppProds;
}
```

**Test Class**

```
@isTest
public class UnitPriceUpdateTest {

    @testSetup
    static void dataSetup() {

        Product2 p = new Product2();
        p.Name = 'TestProduct';
        insert p;

        Id pricebookId = Test.getStandardPricebookId();

        PricebookEntry pbe = new PricebookEntry(
            Pricebook2Id = pricebookId,
            Product2Id = p.Id,
            UnitPrice = 10000,
            IsActive = true);
        insert pbe;

        List<Opportunity> opps = new List<Opportunity>();

        for (Integer i = 0; i < 200; i++) {

            Opportunity o = new Opportunity(
                Name = 'Test Opp' + i,
                CloseDate = date.today() + 1,
                StageName = 'Prospecting');
            opps.add(o);
        }
        insert opps;

        List<OpportunityLineItem> oppProds = new List<OpportunityLineItem>();

        for(Opportunity o : opps) {
            OpportunityLineItem oli = new OpportunityLineItem(
                OpportunityId = o.Id,
                PricebookEntryId = pbe.Id,
                UnitPrice = 100,
                Quantity = 1,
                Sales_Price1__c = 100,
                Description = '<0>');
            oppProds.add(oli);
        }
        insert oppProds;
    }

    static testMethod void testNewSoftRev() {

        List<OpportunityLineItem> oppProds1 = [SELECT Id, Sales_Price1__c FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE Description = '<0>'];

        test.startTest();

        for(OpportunityLineItem oli : oppProds1) {
            oli.Sales_Price1__c = 200;
        }
        update oppProds1;

        test.stopTest();

    // Retrieve the updated Opportunity Products using an SOQL query here
    // then use system.assert to check that the correct UnitPrice has been calculated.
    // This is not necessary to achieve 100% code coverage but it ensures that your code
    // has done what it's supposed to (and hasn't been impacted by changes in your org in the future).
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks again for your earlier responses.  I've been on Holiday the past 2 weeks but will revisit this again soon.  I plan to read and learn the Apex Tutorials you copied a link too, but this may take me sometime to get to and learn of course......

Comment: ...Final thought that may help, is that I'm finding the workaround for now is to get users to simply 'Edit All' and Save again. Then the Calculated Maintenance is using the previous Roll-up amount on the Opportunity that hasn't changed and as such is also the current and thus correct.  When I can dedicate more time I'm hoping I can get the calc to fire after save or maybe just have it save again (not ideal but possibly an easier opt until I learn more).  Thanks again and to everyone else who responded including Ankz Davé (when I learn Apex much further this will likely help too :-)

Comment: Just wanted to visit back and say a big thank you for pointing out those tutorial back in Aug.  I've since learned a lot and been applying to some solutions.  Still lots to learn though :-) - Jonny

Comment: @Jonny you're welcome and thanks for the extra feedback, that's great to hear! David Liu's blog is still my favorite resource but since you posted your question Salesforce created [Trailhead](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/) which is definitely worth checking out too..

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get much about fields from question but got little basic,
Try this *logic*:

Trigger:

```
trigger OpportunityReScheduling on Opportunity (after update, before update, after insert) 
{
    for (Opportunity o: Trigger.new)
    {
        if (Trigger.isAfter || Trigger.isInsert)
        {
            OpportunitySchedulingHandler.ScheduleServiceDateUpdate(o.id);   
        }
    }
}
```

Class:

```
public with sharing class OpportunitySchedulingHandler {


    public static void ScheduleServiceDateUpdate(String oppid)
    {
        List<Opportunity> oliList = [SELECT Id, Name, Amount, (SELECT Id, UnitPrice, OpportunityId from OpportunityLineItems) from Opportunity where Id =:oppid];
        List<OpportunityLineItem> oliUpdateList = new List<OpportunityLineItem>();
        for(Opportunity x : oliList)
        {
            for(OpportunityLineItem oli : x.OpportunityLineItems)
            {
                oli.UnitProce = x.Amount;
                oliUpdateList.add(oli);
            }
        }
        if(!oliUpdateList.isEmpty()) 
        {
            update oliUpdateList;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you want to do it this way  - you are doing SOQL and DML inside of a for loop (the loop on Trigger.new)